# Rails - Reload JS and CSS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, cocoon-gem

I'm using [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to dynamically add fields to my forms, when buttons are pressed.

The problem is that I need to run part of my JS code to apply design changes. I'm running the JS with Document Ready, however I only add those fields afterwards.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('form.form').materialForm();
});
```

I'm using [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Material-Design-Styled-Text-Fields-with-jQuery-CSS3.html) simple material design framework, and I just need to run this:

```
$('form.form').materialForm();
```

Ideas?

**EDIT:**

HAML code:

```
.container
.row
  .col-xs-1.col-xs-offset-2
    %span.step.step-small.step-secondary 3
  .col-xs-6
    = f.fields_for :list_impacts do |ia|
      = render "folder/folder1/impacts", f: ia
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add impacts', f, :list_impacts, partial: 'folder/folder1/impacts'
```

Comment: Please post your button HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [callbacks](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items). So something like

```
$('form.form').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
  $(insertedItem).materialForm();
});
```